# Suggest friends based off of mutual friends

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

I've already looked around on this site, but none seem to be exactly what I'm looking for. A lot of them are talking about how Facebook does it, or how Twitter does it to suggest followers, but even then they don't give any straight-forward answer.
All of the ones I find are just calculating mutual friends using two user IDs.

I want to be able to take the logged in user's ID, go through their friends, and go through THEIR friends to calculate the ones who have the most mutual friends with the logged in user, to suggest people to add that have the most mutual friends.

I'm using PHP and MySQL for this. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how I'd do it.

My friendship table looks something like this:

```
---------------------------------
| friend1 |  friend2  | pending |
---------------------------------
|    1    |     2     |    0    |
|    2    |     1     |    0    |
|    3    |     1     |    0    |
|    1    |     3     |    0    |
---------------------------------
```

This table is showing that user_id 1 is friends with 2 and 3
and 2 isn't friends with 3, but is friends with 1.

So, if the user was logged into user_id 2, I want it to suggest user_id 3 because both of them are friends with user_id 1.

---

What I have so far:

```
  public function friendList($user_id = null){
    if(!$user_id){
      $user_id = $this->_data->user_id;
    }
    $query = "SELECT friend2 FROM user_friends WHERE pending = 0 AND ((friend1 = ".$user_id.") AND (friend2 IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE active = 1 AND user_id = friend2)))";
    $data = $this->_db->hardquery($query);
    return $data->results();
  }
  public function suggestUsers(){
    $user_id = $this->_data->user_id;
    $my_friends = array();
    $suggest_friends = array();
    foreach($this->friendList() as $friend){
      array_push($my_friends,$friend->friend2);
    }
    foreach($my_friends as $friend_id){
      foreach($this->friendList($friend_id) as $friendOfFriend){
        $friendOfFriend = $friendOfFriend->friend2;
        if(!in_array($friendOfFriend,$my_friends) && $friendOfFriend != $user_id){
          array_push($suggest_friends,$friendOfFriend);
        }
      }
    }
    foreach($suggest_friends as $sgf){
      $sgf = new user($sgf);
      $sgf = $sgf->data();
      echo "<a href=\"#\">".$sgf->display."</a><br>";
    }
  }
```

---

and it works, listing off friends who are friends of the user's friends, but don't have the user added...
HOWEVER, I can't sort it based off of who has the most mutual friends, which I guess is okay (Though I'd like if I could), 
but it also doesn't seem like a very efficient way to do it..

It seems like this would take a lot of resources having to go through all of the user's friends, especially if the user has a couple hundred to a thousand friends added, and they have a couple hundred to a thousand added, etc.

I'm not that familiar with advanced SQL, so I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this.

Comment: are all friendships listed twice, once as `friend1` and once as `friend2`?

Comment: @Sean yes, for each friendship, there's two rows. friend1 is always the logged in user, and friend2 is always the other user. (This is for simplicity, I realize it may not be the best way to do it efficiency-wise)

Comment: @Axiom Can you see my answer. It returns all the mutual friends. If any problem, comment on the answer. I'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt at doing this with 1 query. The idea is to select the `friend2` list, and join it to a select where the `friend2` is `friend1`. Using `GROUP BY`, we are then able to return the rows ordered by the relevance of the friendship, and everyone that is friends with that person.

```
SELECT 
    a.friend2, 
    COUNT(*) as relevance, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.friend1 ORDER BY a.friend1) as mutual_friends 
FROM 
    user_friends a
JOIN 
    user_friends b
ON  (
     b.friend2 = a.friend1
     AND b.pending = 0 
     AND b.friend1 = LOGGED_IN_USER
    )
WHERE 
    a.pending = 0
AND 
    a.friend2 != LOGGED_IN_USER
GROUP BY 
    a.friend2
ORDER BY 
    relevance DESC;
```

A [sqlFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dbf0/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dbf0/3)

**Edit**

In my original query I forgot to exclude any user that is already friends with the `LOGGED_IN_USER`. By using a `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` where a friendship does not exist, this should return your desired result.

```
SELECT 
    a.friend2, 
    COUNT(*) as relevance, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.friend1 ORDER BY a.friend1) as mutual_friends 
FROM 
    user_friends a
JOIN 
    user_friends b
ON  (
     b.friend2 = a.friend1
     AND b.pending = 0 
     AND b.friend1 = LOGGED_IN_USER
    )
LEFT JOIN
    user_friends c
ON
    (
     c.friend2 = a.friend2 
     AND c.pending = 0 
     AND c.friend1 = LOGGED_IN_USER
    )     
WHERE 
    a.pending = 0
AND
    c.friend1 IS NULL
AND 
    a.friend2 != LOGGED_IN_USER
GROUP BY 
    a.friend2
ORDER BY 
    relevance DESC;
```

updated [sqlFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38b5c/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38b5c/2)

Comment: Going through the results of this in PHP is a bit confusing... It seems as if it's returning a list of mutual friends and such, but how would I go about telling which ones aren't added with the current user? Here's what I'm trying: http://pastebin.com/JKLyP3nW - This is showing some friends I have added, and some I don't. Sorry if I'm not doing something correctly, like I said I'm a noob when it comes to advanced SQL queries.. lol

Comment: For better reference, here's a fiddle using data from actual table (it just containing user IDs I don't think it'll be an issue) - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38b5c/1 - It should return the following IDs: `24`, `25`, `43`, `44`, `138` and `139` as far as I'm aware. My ID being `1`.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an update. I forgot to exclude the current friends of the logged in user. Also, the [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38b5c/2) does not show `24`, as you have `(21,24,1)`, so `pending != 0`,

Comment: You're correct, I didn't realize that. Thank you so much, it works great!

Answer (score -1):

You Can do that by single sql query. You should write sql inner sub query for this. Look at following query. It returns mutual friend ids when given logged in user id.

```
$sql= "SELECT `friend2` FROM `user_friends` WHERE `friend1` IN (SELECT `friend2` FROM `user_friends` WHERE `friend1`=$logged_in_user_id) AND `friend2` != $logged_in_user_id";
```

Just pass the logged in user id for variable `$logged_in_user_id`. If you want to know how to write sql sub queries, You can learn that by looking [Sql Sub Queries link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm).

Following function will out put mutual friends data.

```
public function testSuggest(){
    $logged_in_user_id = $this->_data->user_id;
    $suggest_friends = array();
    $sql = "SELECT `friend2` FROM `user_friends` WHERE `friend1` IN (SELECT `friend2` FROM `user_friends` WHERE `friend1`=$logged_in_user_id) AND `friend2` != $logged_in_user_id AND `friend2` IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `active`=1 AND `user_id` = `friend2`)";
    $data = $this->_db->hardquery($sql);
    foreach($data->results() as $mutuals){
          array_push($suggest_friends,$mutuals);
    }
    foreach($suggest_friends as $sgf){
      $sgf_user = new user($sgf);
      $sgf_user_data = $sgf_user->data();
      echo "<a href=\"".config::get('site/url')."/u/".$sgf_user_data->username."\">".$sgf_user_data->display."</a><br>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: While I wasn't the one who downvoted it, it still doesn't work as expected. I would like to be able to get JUST the suggest friends using a query (if possible). I had to do some tweaking to get it to work as expected, and it still uses 4 `foreach()` loops to get it to work the same as my function above. (And still can't sort by who has most mutuals) - Link to final function: http://pastebin.com/1qFnax4y  - However to my knowledge, it does seem to be working better since it's less-querying from the database. Just not necessarily what I wanted. Thanks, though.

Comment: This returns a list of my friends' friends, it seems. I see users more than once using that exact function. (Switching `foreach($data->results() as $mutuals->friend2)` since it's pulling `friend2`). Here's a screenshot of what I mean, since I can't explain it well: http://i.imgur.com/k2mSIyA.png | This is why I added the extra `foreach()` loops in the pastebin link. The pastebin link returns friends I'm not yet friends with, but have mutuals.To make it clear, I'm not looking for a list of mutuals, but a list of users to suggest for the logged in user to add based on who has most mutuals.